# Not able to update Swagger-UI version to desired version in ASP .net6

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I need to upgrade the version of Swagger UI to above 4.14.2 but even though the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version is 5.5.1, in my case the generated Swagger UI shows version 3.

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore versions:

[image]

Swagger UI version:

[image]

I have checked the Swagger UI version using this [link](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/version-detection/).

Comment: Is updating Swashbuckle an option? The latest Swashbuckle version 6.4.0 includes Swagger UI 4.10.3.

Comment: If you try to update your Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to version 6.2.3,will it be solved?